# Does LPC111x series support MOV instruction with High registers?

Tags: assembly, lpc, machine-code

[UM10398 LPC111x/LPC11Cxx User manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10398.pdf) Rev. 12.3 — 10 June 2014 says

> In these instructions, Rd, and Rm must only specify R0-R7

in "28.5.5.5.3 Restrictions" in "28.5.5.5 MOV and MVN".

On the other hand, "28.5.5.5.5 Example" in UM10398 says

> ```
> MOVS R0, #0x000B ; Write value of 0x000B to R0, flags get updated
> MOVS R1, #0x0 ; Write value of zero to R1, flags are updated
> MOV R10, R12 ; Write value in R12 to R10, flags are not updated
> MOVS R3, #23 ; Write value of 23 to R3
> MOV R8, SP ; Write value of stack pointer to R8
> MVNS R2, R0 ; Write inverse of R0 to the R2 and update flags
> ```

In this example, `R10`, `R12`, `R8` and `SP` are used despite of they doesn't seem `R0-R7`. (`SP` seems equivalent to `R13`, according to UM10398 28.4.1.3 Core registers)

One more thing is that when I read [re-ejected-thumbref2.pdf](http://www.coranac.com/files/gba/re-ejected-thumbref2.pdf), I found

> MOV Rd, Rm 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 H1 H2 _ Rm _ _ Rd _

and this suggests High registers are available for use with `MOV` instruction. This document also say that

> Rd or Rm must be a *high register*

about this `MOV Rd, Rm` instruction.

Although instructions with `S` (with flag update) are not on this document (in this document instructions without `S` are said to updating flags) and this document should be for another CPU (maybe one used in GBA, according to the URL path), I used this document as reference, hoping that instruction set of LPC111x is similar to one described in this document.

In conclusion, can I do

- `MOV R0, R1` (Low registers to Low registers)
- `MOV R8, R1` (Low registers to High registers)
- `MOV R0, R9` (High registers to Low registers)
- `MOV R8, R9` (High registers to High registers)

in LPC111x (or LPC1114FN28/102, if you need specific CPU pointed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LPC1114FN28 has an ARM Cortex-M0 core, so [its MOV instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0432c/CHDCICDF.html) has no low/high restrictions on registers. However, because the Thumb instruction set didn't originally have a MOV low to low instruction, for compatibility your assembler may use an ADDS instruction for MOV R0, R1.

For example if I assemble the following with `as -mcpu=cortex-m0 t117.s`:

```
    # .syntax unified
    .thumb

    MOV R0, R1
    MOV R8, R1
    MOV R0, R9
    MOV R8, R9
```

The object file created contains the following instructions as show by `objdump -d`:

```
   0:   1c08            adds    r0, r1, #0
   2:   4688            mov     r8, r1
   4:   4648            mov     r0, r9
   6:   46c8            mov     r8, r9
```

By uncommenting the `.syntax unified` directive and reassembling it the disassembly ends up as expected:

```
   0:   4608            mov     r0, r1
   2:   4688            mov     r8, r1
   4:   4648            mov     r0, r9
   6:   46c8            mov     r8, r9
```

I believe the statement "In these instructions, Rd, and Rm must only specify R0-R7" was only meant to apply to the MOVS instruction which has this restriction.